# Why am I getting 0.0 with this code?

Tags: c#, math, percentage

When I enter, in the Windows Calculator utility, "15036/18218*100=" it returns 82.53375782193435

What I really want is 17.47 (100 - 82.53), but that's beside the point at the moment.

With this code:

```
// Example: thisQty == 3182; totalQty == 18218
private string GetPercentage(int thisQty, int totalQty)
{
    int diff = totalQty - thisQty; // this equates to 15036
    double prcntg = (diff/totalQty)*100; // this equates to 0.0 for some reason
    return string.Format("{0}%", prcntg);
}
```

...I'm getting 0.0 for the prcntg value. Why? ISTM that this is the same operation that I'm doing by hand in the Calculator utility. Why doesn't it return 82.53375782193435?

Comment: You have to cast diff to double, double prcntg = ((double)diff/totalQty)*100;

Comment: When you've got an answer that adds something, post it as a self-answer. Don't edit 'a solution' into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dividing of 2 `int`s will be an `int` even if the correct mathematical answer is with a fraction.

In order to have it keep the decimal part you must divide with a number of a type that holds the fraction part (like `double` or `decimal`):

```
Console.WriteLine(GetPercentage(3182, 18218));

private string GetPercentage(int thisQty, int totalQty)
{
   int diff = totalQty - thisQty; // this equates to 15036
   double prcntg = (diff / (double)totalQty) * 100;
   return string.Format("{0}%", prcntg);
}
```

*BTW - it doesn't matter if you cast to `double` the `diff` or the `totalQty` - for both it will do the `/` operation returning a `double` - which means keeping the fraction part*

Answer (score 2):

You are using an integer value, (which doesn't store factional part), so cast it to double, or use the parameter type as double (my recommendation). Your operation, `15036/18218` resolves to, 0.82 and in an integer value that is stored as 0... Where finally `0 * 100` is going to resolve to 0 anyways and that is where you get the result.

Try this instead,

```
private string GetPercentage(double thisQty, double totalQty)
{
    double diff = totalQty - thisQty; // this equates to 15036
    double prcntg = (diff/totalQty) * 100.0; // this equates to 0.0 for some reason
    return string.Format("{0}%", prcntg);
}
```

This would have the fractional part too and you will get the result.

Comment: How is this different from my original code?

Comment: Diff needs to be a double.  It's still an INT.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, the parameters that are passed in, "thisQty" and "totalQty" are now doubles instead of int.  However, the "diff" variable also needs to be of the type double.

Comment: @GiladGreen Actually it will work because `totalQty` is now a `double` and if you do operations with an `int` and a `double` it will cast the `int` to a `double` and do the `double` operation.  Though there was no point in casting the difference into an `int` on the first line.

Comment: Ops sorry missed the change of the double in the signature

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, I changed the parameter types but missed the `diff` type. Thank you Jay for the edit. But one of them is a double and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gilad Green's answer, here is what I ended up with, which gives the value I ultimately want, and also rounds the value to an integer:

```
private string GetPercentage(int thisQty, int totalQty)
{
    int diff = totalQty - thisQty;
    double prcntg = (diff / (double)totalQty) * 100;
    prcntg = 100 - prcntg;
    int roundedPercent = Convert.ToInt32(prcntg);
    return string.Format("{0}%", roundedPercent);
}
```